# Helm charts with AGPL licenses

Tags: gpl, agpl

Some helm charts (for example https://github.com/minio/charts/blob/master/LICENSE) are using AGPL license. Helm chart is an instruction for helm https://helm.sh/ to deploy a cloud application to kubernetes.

I'm developing a large cloud based proprietary application, it uses helm charts for deployment. It is deployed both to cloud administered by my organization and to onprem installations administered by clients. In the second case the helm charts are distributed.

I want to include an AGPL-licensed helm chart for minio as part of umbrella helm charts for my product. Does it require me to open source all helm charts for my application(actually they are already distributed in open source)? Does it require me to open source the whole code of my application?

In other words - where ends the "covered work" for AGPL-licensed helm chart for minio?

Comment: Hmm, since a helm chart is just a deployment script and not a software that is accessible over a network, I'd expect AGPL and GPL to be equivalent in this case, and to not extend to other helm charts or even to your application. But I'm not very familiar with the technical details.

Comment: @amon your comment is starting to get upvotes, and provides a perfectly good answer (to my mind) given that you (like me) claim to have no particular grasp of the technical details of helm charts.  Do you fancy simply rewriting it as an answer, in the continuing absence of any better one?